# Significado de una persona que es "tan capa"

Tags: vocabulario

He constatado el uso de la expresión a efectos de "eres tan capa" como un cumplido en los comentarios de redes sociales en particular por los perfiles argentinos. Me parece que la palabra "capa" aquí es abreviatura de capaz, o sea se refiere a la persona como muy hábil, ¿sí? Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: [Buena/o en lo que haces, experta/o, ducho, inteligente, excepcional, admirable, capaz, etc](https://www.jergasdehablahispana.org/index.php?tipobusqueda=3&palabra=capo&newp=capo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Capo**

Del it. capo; propiamente 'cabeza', y este del lat. caput.

1. m. Jefe de una mafia, especialmente de narcotraficantes.
2. m. coloq. Arg., Bol., Par. y Ur. jefe (‖ superior de una corporación u oficio).

**3. m. coloq. Arg., Bol., Par. y Ur. Persona con poder y prestigio o muy entendida en una determinada materia. Es un capo en física cuántica.**

https://dle.rae.es/capo

De la última acepción se deriva que es una persona muy hábil, que tiene gran experiencia en algún trabajo o actividad o posee amplios conocimientos sobre una materia en concreto, así alguien es un genio, un portento, un fenómeno con gran capacidad, un jefe figurativo en algo, en definitiva es una especie de halago.

Ejem. Esta doctora es muy capa en traumatología; los autores de este libro son unos capos en la literaria de este país.

Los argentinos lo utilizan habitualmente de forma reiterativa, ¡ chee, sos un capo! te pasaste, loco, gracias, sos un capo... para las matemáticas...

**P.D.** "tan capa". Aquí la locución "tan capa" es solo una variación de "capa", donde "tan" expresa un grado más elevado en la propiedad de aquello a lo que hace referencia el contexto "sos tan capa" (eres el mejor, eres muy bueno en una actividad...).

Comment: En el contexto de redes sociales que proporcionó el OP es una forma de halago(1) más informal(está en el link), es como decir "Eres buena en lo que haces/¡Me gusta!/¡Eres la mejor!(más neutral)" y eso es para lo que sea que esté haciendo, lo de jefe queda para otro contexto (2). A un doctor/profesor/físico cuántico NO se le dice "eres capo" formalmente a menos que estés bromeando, que haya una cierta confianza o amistad, La forma que señalas como reiterativa es porque lo ultilizan como apelativo(3) ¡Che! ¡Oye! ¡Hey! ¡Amigo! ¡Loco vení para acá! porque no hay un físico nuclear en todos lados.

Comment: Hola cocteau, llevas razón, pues la locución en sí es "tan capa", y ahora que lo pienso quizás extrapole la información del sentido "capo" a "tan capa", cuando recordaba a mis amigos argentinos en contextos de broma, como tu dices, y se referían a alguien por ejemplo, que era un gran artista, como "puto capo". Aunque al final el sentido de "sos el mejor", es el que quería que prevaleciera o se acabara percibiendo, incluido aquellos contextos en los que se está de broma. Gracias por recordármelo.